# How Can I Read a Large Integer from a Buffer into an Integer in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, buffer

I am having difficulty getting an integer from a buffer in iOS.

To read a string, I am using:

```
output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer lenght:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent initWithBytes for integers.

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the buffer can be cast directly to the integer value.

```
int original = 0xBADF00D;
void *buffer = &original;

//Cast the void* as an int* and then dereference the value
int intFromBuffer = *(int*)buffer;

NSLog(@"0x%X 0x%X", original, intFromBuffer);
```

Output:

**0xBADF00D 0xBADF00D**

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for that!  I am assuming this will work for very large numbers?

Comment: Belay that - just got google to convert 1 billion in to hex and looked at the intFromBuffer and it worked!

Comment: Yes it will work with very large numbers but make sure you are using the correct integer size for what is inside of the buffer. If the buffer points to a 32bit unsigned int then use a 32bit unsigned int, same goes for 64 bit numbers. This is important so that you do not end up with garbage numbers or worse reading memory you do not have access to.